# 10GB Ethernet switch for iSCSI for under $3000?

Tags: switch

Our network vendor is telling us to upgrade our [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) SAN to 10GB. We are game.

But the network switches alone are $4500 each (or more), and we need 2! (He sells Dell gear.)

Are there reliable options that are less coin?

Answer (score 2):

Wellll, this site is kinda quiet. Found a thread on spiceworks which is much more active. Found a couple of useful paths:

- Dell X4012 is a 12port, 10GB managed, for $1239.
- Netgear 12-Port ProSafe 10 Gigabit Smart Switch XS712T // Netgear has unmanaged option for sub $900, and managed optio for ~$1400

Comment: Can you add a link to the thread?